# Fragment not attached to context because of Handler?

Tags: android-fragments, runnable, android-context, android-handler

I made a Handler and a Runnable to wait 2 seconds until an animation starts but if I will leave the application in this time or if i will open another Fragment it crashes with the exception fragment not attached to context because of Handler.
What can I do? I tried many solution from the web but nothing worked for me and no using the startoffset method of the animation isn't a solution.
Thanks for your help.

(If I leave the Handler and the Runnable out of the code it works fine)

```
 Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                float dip = 20f;
                Resources r = getResources();
                float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                        dip,
                        r.getDisplayMetrics()
                );
                Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
                        Animation.ABSOLUTE, -(willkommen.getHeight() + px));
                outtoRight.setDuration(300);
                outtoRight.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        willkommen.setLayoutParams(params);
                        firstlaunchueberblick=true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                grid.startAnimation(outtoRight);
                willkommen.startAnimation(outtoRight);
            }
        },2000);
```

That's my code inside the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);

That's the solution. I read that i can also pass null as paramter to remove all Callbacks but that doesn't work;